# c# mudar source da picturebox

Tags: c#, picturebox

Tenho uma tabela com 4 campos tipo Image. Coloquei um pictureBox e nas propriedades Data, em DataBindings, linkei ele com um dos campos da tabela, o campo image1, ao executar o programa está trazendo certinho a imagem do campo image1 da tabela. Assim ele pode fazer mudanças, desenhar ou apagar e ao clicar em salvar, salvará as mudanças no campo da tabela ao qual está linkado "image1".

Como faço pro usuário, ao clicar em um botão, mudar a qual campo da tabela essa pictureBox está linkada? Por exemplo se clicar no botao 2, a pictureBox mostra a imagem que está no campo image2 da tabela, e qualquer mudança feita, ao clicar em salvar, já salvará no "image2".

Estou usando o database local do visual studio, apenas arrastando e soltando os campos do painel "DataSources". Não uso nenhum codigo de sql.

Comment: mas como ta o source do picturebox ?

Comment: Eu selecionei o pictureBox. Ai la na janela propriedades do visual studio cliquei em DataBindings, ele abre uma tela onde escolhi minha tabela, ai mostra todos os campos dessa tabela, e escolhi o "image1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que pesquisei, você adicionou um `Control.DataBindings` ao fazer pela interface gráfica do Visual Studio. Com isso, acredito que você pode simplesmente limpar a coleção e adicionar outra Source:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         pictureBox1.DataBindings.Clear();
         pictureBox1.DataBindings.Add("Image", SeuDataSet.Tables["suaTabelaDeImagens"], "coluna2");

    }
```

Documentação:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.control.databindings(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.binding(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.controlbindingscollection(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: o que seria esse "suaTabelaDeImagens" coloquei numero 0 por ser minha primeira tabela deu erro de Null, coloquei o nome da tabela entre aspas, deu error "converter string to int". E Obrigado pela ajuda,

Comment: você deve ter um DataSet na sua aplicação, dentro dele, qual a tabela de imagens... como é sua primeira, 0 deveria funcionar, mas apenas se o DataSet já estiver carregado

Comment: Está dando um erro de Conversão inválida de 'System.DBNull' em 'System.Drawing.Image'. Pode ser porque o campo que estou digitando ainda não tem nada, esta vazio? A tabela está vazia mesmo, o usuario que aperta o botao e seleciona a imagem do pc dele com OpenFileDialog. Pode ser isso??

Comment: acredito que sim.

Comment: Consegui, Era exatamente isso, meu amigo. Obrigado por toda ajuda que vc dá.